Unable to connect to MongoDB Cluster in deployed Springboot App on Google Cloud Run
I am trying to connect my Java Springboot backend, deployed to Google Cloud Run as a service, to my MongoDB cluster. The deployment itself is successful, and I have added the connection string as an environment variable. But in the logs I am consistently getting a connection refused in the exception seen below:
2024-07-14T01:15:32.428Z  INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

2024-07-14 02:15:32.433 BST
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.lambda$open$0(SocketStream.java:84) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:84) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:211) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:196) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:156) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:549) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:76) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:104) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:78) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
    ... 4 common frames omitted

To resolve this I've tried the following:
Checked over the cloud run service:
App confirmed to run locally and connect to the cluster and DB stored.
Container port is 8080.
Dockerfile built to build and run spring boot app in container. Confirmed to run.
MongoDB connection string is added as an environment variable.
Networking: Connect to a VPC for outbound traffic -> using created vpc servless connector.
Traffic Routing: Route only reuqests to private IPs to the VPC.
VPC network:
I created a serverless VPC access connector using the default network, and an egress firewall rule to allow mongoDB traffic for the standard mongoDB port 27017. This is set to priority 1000.
Cloud NAT:
I additionally created a public-type cloud NAT gateway that using the same default network, and a created cloud router (it does not advertise IP ranges or subnets). BGN identifier is set to automatic.
Cloud NAT Mapping is set to the following:
High Availability: yes.
Source endpoint type: VM instances, GKE nodes, Serverless.
Source subnets & IP ranges: All subnets' primary and secondary IP ranges.
Cloud NAT IP address: xx.xxx.xx.xxx this also matches to the generic 0.0.0.0/0
MongoDB:

static IP addresss
0.0.0.0/0
CIDR from vpc connector (e.g. 10.8.0.0/28)

all whitelisted.
connection String:
"mongodb+srv://admin:generatedPassword@cluster0.fqwmsk8.mongodb.net/InventoryDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

Any advice or pointers will be appreciated thank you!

According to error message you try to connect to localhost, this does not match to all the IP settings you have listed.

This is a point of confusion for me as well. I am using the connection string so I am surprised that it is attempting to connect to localhost. Might I be missing something in the connection string?

Without the connection string nobody would be able to help you.

I thought that might be a security issue so I didn't include it. I will edit the message and add it without the password

Of course, you should not disclose your password
